# how to use the type FLOAT8 [] with NPGSQL / Postgres

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I have this in my schema:

```
f_gain_factor_notional        FLOAT8       NOT NULL,
f_profits                     FLOAT8 []    NOT NULL,
f_fees                        FLOAT8 []    NOT NULL,
```

How can I write to the FLOAT8 [] type using npgsql?

There doesn't seem to be a built-in type Sql.doubleArray or any equivalent. I see Sql.stringArray, Sql.intArray, etc.

How can this be handled?

---

Edit: these are the types available

[image]

---

Edit: here is some code:

```
            let queryInsert =
                $"
                -- insert row
                ... skipped for brevity
                ",
                [[

                    "@f_gain_factor_notional",          Sql.double (float results.FixedResults.GainFactorNotional)
                    "@f_profits",                       Sql.stringArray (results.FixedResults.Profits |> List.map string |> List.toArray)
                    "@f_fees",                          Sql.stringArray (results.FixedResults.Fees    |> List.map string |> List.toArray)
                    "@f_margin",                        Sql.stringArray (results.FixedResults.Margin  |> List.map string |> List.toArray)
                    "@f_relative_drawdown",             Sql.double (float results.FixedResults.RelativeDrawdown)
                    "@f_absolute_drawdown",             Sql.double (float results.FixedResults.AbsoluteDrawdown)
                    "@f_realized_profit",               
...
```

This is F# code, but the issue is identical with C#:

I've to cast the dotnet types to npgsql type.

So, for a string, I can do:

```
Sql.string "yo"
```

for a string array, I can do:

```
Sql.stringArray [| "hello"; "world |]
```

for a double array, I... can't do, since Sql.doubleArray doesn't exist. Sql.intArray exists, but no double/float/decimal.

Comment: We can close this question, this was a shortcoming of the lib I'm using. I did a PR to update it. Sorry to have wasted people's time on this.

Answer (score 1):

Npgsql maps regular .NET arrays to PostgreSQL array types, so you should be able to simply use .NET `double[]` to map PG `float8[]`.

Comment: but how do I create a npgsql .net value for it? for example I have Sql.stringArray, Sql.intArray, etc but no Sql.floatArray. I've edited the question to show the options.

Comment: None of the above types (SqlValue, Sql.stringArray, Sql.intArray) have anything to do with Npgsql or PostgreSQL. Just create a plain .NET array (`new double[10]`) and use that.

Comment: If the above isn't clear, please post a short code sample to show us what you're actually trying to do, e.g. how are you currently handling an int array.

Comment: I added some sample code. I'm starting to wonder if it's not an omission in the F# lib

Comment: Which F# lib are you using? Nothing about that is specified above - I'm not aware of any Sql.anything, so that must be a specific thing from some specific lib. At the pure Npgsql level, you just use plain .NET arrays.